# Stacked stripchart in R getting cut off?

Tags: r, stripchart

I am trying to create a dotplot for some sampling distributions. I have created one for the medians of random samples of a uniform distribution. However the chart is getting truncated erroneously at the top. I have tried to reset with a ylim vector to no avail.

```
B <- replicate(500,median(sample(c(0:9),20,replace=T)))
stripchart(B, method="stack",pch=16,offset =0.5,at=0)
```

[dotplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDzei.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example...

Comment: Updated above. -AFH

Answer (score -1):

I could not make it work using `stripchart` and I don't know why. I hope `barplot` delivers what you need:

```
barplot(table(B))
```

Hopefully you can work with that.

Comment: Yes, I too can make it work as another type of graph. I am hoping to get a dotplot format, however.

Comment: Why do you need `dotplot`?